# IBM WAS 7 Error

Tags: spring, websphere, classloader

I'm trying to use My Eclipse Blue with WAS 7.  This error occurs on my local sever which I manually configured based on the settings from my IBM RAD 7.0 local server which works.  I know that the CAR file from RAD is not compatible with MEB.  Please help me determine what this error means and how to attempt to fix it.

```
DEBUG filter.DelegatingFilterProxy - Initializing filter 'springSecurityFilterChain'

[9/18/15 10:16:11:051 CDT] 00000016 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[AxisServlet]: org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [common-context-default], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common-context-default' defined in URL [file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/NPISRV0Z/installedApps/LPB68HV2Node11Cell/PremierProviderCrosswalk_ear.ear/PremierProviderCrosswalk_service.jar/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceProxy' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceProxy' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:409)
    at com.hcsc.eas.frameworkx.web.context.DynamicContextLoader.loadParentContext(DynamicContextLoader.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:193)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1718)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:732)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:617)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1128)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:944)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:741)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1273)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5305)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1278)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2050)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:389)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:332)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:603)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:565)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:243)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.invoke(SOAPConnector.java:464)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnector.service(SOAPConnector.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnection.handleRequest(SOAPConnection.java:65)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.readAndHandleRequest(HttpConnection.java:733)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.HttpConnection.run(HttpConnection.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1660)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'common-context-default' defined in URL [file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer70/profiles/NPISRV0Z/installedApps/LPB68HV2Node11Cell/PremierProviderCrosswalk_ear.ear/PremierProviderCrosswalk_service.jar/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceProxy' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceProxy' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:907)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.access.SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.useBeanFactory(SingletonBeanFactoryLocator.java:397)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceProxy' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceProxy' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceProxy' while setting bean property 'delegate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceProxy' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceProxy' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'crosswalkServiceImpl' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'crosswalkServiceImpl' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-service-default.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'providerDao' while setting bean property 'providerDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 98 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providerDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=$Proxy27, method=getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Ljava/util/Date;Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin;, pc=0
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:72)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:515)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:589)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.getProxy(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getProxy(ProxyFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance(ProxyFactoryBean.java:316)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean.getObject(ProxyFactoryBean.java:242)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 113 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `getXwalkPfinForPfinKeyIdAndDate(Date,String)` which is supposed to return a `com/hcsc/premier/provider/crosswalk/common/domaindto/XwalkPfin` causes a class outside your application to try to load a class within. I would look within that method to get understanding of what it is trying to do, and with what classes.

Check your application classloading configuration - you can try PARENT_LAST in WebSphere to see if this resolves the issue, or you can use the [WebSphere class loader viewer](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/ttrb_classload_viewer.html?lang=en) and compare the application classpath from a working deployment (from RAD) and the broken one (MEB). I believe you'll see either a different set of jars in your WAR/EAR or perhaps a different shared library setup in the broken scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is `java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013`.
IBM has [support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249) describing your issue.